# How to upload a file to s3 from a file upload form after modifying it with PIL?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, boto

Here is the code stuff:

```
app.config['DEBUG']= True


if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['file_submit']:
        print request.form
        print request.files['image']
        if request.files['image']:
            print 'foshhh'
            image_file = request.files['image']
            img = PIL.Image.open(image_file.stream)
            print img
            if request.form['make_transparent']:
                threshold=100
                print 'changin sizesd'
                dist=5
                # np.asarray(img) is read only. Wrap it in np.array to make it modifiable.
                arr=np.array(np.asarray(img))
                r,g,b,a=np.rollaxis(arr,axis=-1)
                mask=((r>threshold)
                    & (g>threshold)
                    & (b>threshold)
                    & (np.abs(r-g)<dist)
                    & (np.abs(r-b)<dist)
                    & (np.abs(g-b)<dist)
                    )
                arr[mask,3]=0
                img=Image.fromarray(arr,mode='RGBA')
            if request.form['change_size']:
                img = Image.open('out.png')
                img.thumbnail(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
                img.save('out.png',"PNG")

            img.save('out.png',"PNG")
            print os.path.getsize("out.png")   #from answer
            assert os.path.isfile("out.png")   #from answer
            conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
            b = conn.get_bucket('snappie.watermarks')
            k = Key(b)
            k.key = "test.png"
            k.set_metadata('Content-Type', 'image/png')
            k.set_contents_from_filename("out.png")
            print "got file"
            return redirect("https://s3.amazonaws.com/snappie.watermarks/"+filename)
        else:
            print 'please upload a file to submit the form!'
```

and here is the html form :

```
   <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="file_submit">
            <label>Choose png here.<input type="file" name="image"></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="file_submit" value="yes">
            Change size?<input type="checkbox" name="change_size" value="yes"/>
            Make Background Transparent?<input type="checkbox" name="make_transparent" value="yes"\><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

part of the problem is that It doesn't really give me an error log. You can see that the idea is that there are 2 checkboxes which can modify the image file. If the first one is checked, its "made transparent" and if the second one is checked, it changes the size.

I think I am having issue with the type of the image object when it gets converted and modified, especially when it gets passed into this object:             `k.set_contents_from_filename("out.png")`

Any help here? This is the only output the server logs give me:

```
GET
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2015 15:42:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
POST
ImmutableMultiDict([('file_submit', u'yes')])
<FileStorage: u'birnam_wood.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>
foshhh
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=100x100 at 0x7FDDF4CA6C68>
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2015 15:42:32] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Comment: Did I miss the part in your question where you *clearly* state what the problem is? That is, what do you want to achieve, what is expected behavior and what do you observe instead?

Comment: Well right now when a photo is submitted, there is a server error. So clearly there is an error somewhere. On top of that, I don't believe Im passing the file correctly. Is saving it as "out.png" in both if statements as well as after its done being altered a correct way to do this? Will this "out.png" be stored on the server temporarily with all of the image information? I feel like I could be saving it "as a file" instead of as the filename. In any case, clearly something is wrong currently, hence the error

Comment: Did you put your web application (Flask) into development mode? That is, do you see a traceback when your code raises an unhandled exception?

Comment: you mean like with app.config['DEBUG'] = True? I have not set that because I was told not to on my web server host (pythonanywhere.com) or do you mean a different development mode option?

Comment: In production, you should never do this, right (that is mainly a security measure). For development purposes, you **have to** be able to see tracebacks. How should you debug, otherwise? So, yes, for investigation purposes you have to set `app.config['DEBUG']` to `True`.

Comment: Ok you're right. Ill try this locally with debug mode set to true and perhaps be able to find a more helpful traceback. In the meantime, do you have any recommendations on passing the file through those steps (filename object vs file object, etc)? Clearly its incorrect as it is now.

Comment: Removed comment, made an answer from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I think the server error was formed when there was no "image" object in the request.files dictionary yet the request was sent. Therefore the server had no idea what to do. I fixed it by using request.files.get('image') instead of request.files['image']. Thus if there is no image, it returns None instead of giving a key error.

There was still no trackback, though I know everyone wanted one, because this kind of server error in flask DOES NOT seem to return a traceback. Simply a "Bad request" error message in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

**For proper debugging purposes you really need to look at a traceback. It will tell you what is wrong :-)!!**

Otherwise: I guess your general approach (first create an image file in the file system and then use boto for uploading it) is fine. However, for debugging purposes you could check what `img.save('out.png',"PNG")` leaves behind. You can, for investigation purposes, test if the file exists and otherwise raise an exception: `assert os.path.isfile("out.png")`. Also, you may want to print the file size using `os.path.getsize("out.png")`. As far as I remember working with boto, `k.set_contents_from_filename("out.png")` is the right thing to do then.

That is, your order of doing things is right. Most probably there is an authentication/connection problem with S3, as Dmitry already pointed out. The details of this problem you will find by looking at a Traceback. A boto traceback will contain the error AWS error response.

Comment: hmm setting debug to true doesn't seem to give a traceback. I have updated the question with the code I added, and as you can see from the output, it doesn't give any information on the assert line or the print line before that. In fact, printing anything after those 2 if statements doesn't get printed at all. This doesn't make any sense. Its like those 2 if statements are stopping everything in its tracks? But they shouldn't be called at all, as I am not checking the boxes. Are there any other ways to force it to give me a traceback?

Comment: yeah actually it works if I remove those 2 if statements. Obviously I would like to find a way to keep them though :)

Comment: *"Its like those 2 if statements are stopping everything in its tracks?"* Of course, something in the code is *wrong*, we knew that before! Please please please take this for granted: you *need* that traceback in order to see what is wrong. The traceback will tell you immediately what is wrong. Work on getting this. You can not develop an application without having access to the most important debugging instance in Python: tracebacks due to exceptions.

Comment: You know, without seeing a proper traceback people here do not *want* to debug your code. I have now, because you seem to be cooperative, looked at your code for 30 seconds, and maybe `if request.form['make_transparent']:` raises a KeyError. You are printing `request.form` at some point, and I guess the corresponding output is `ImmutableMultiDict([('file_submit', u'yes')])`. Hence, `'make_transparent'` is not a valid key in that dictionary. This you would have seen *immediately* by looking at the traceback. Neither is `'change_size'`.

Comment: 'make_transparent' is a valid key, i think? So is 'change_size'. They are both input type=hidden on the form. I think you might be right about the key error. But I am not sure why? I do really need that traceback! I'll keep trying to figure out ways to get that

Comment: Less guessing/"thinking", more looking at *facts* is the key to debugging :-). In the mean time you might want to accept this answer, because I really gave you a hell of support and proper debugging *is* the right approach to solve your problem :-).

Comment: eh. its still not the answer to the question. I might want to accept it though because you did put so much support and effort in. I won't know until I find what works. I will accept an answer before that though :P

Comment: Agreed. But you know, if you provide a traceback and it surprises us with something that we did not anticipate before, I am willing to provide further help. But I think I have clarified in multiple places that a traceback (or comparable information, in which ever way you obtain it) is required to proceed. Btw, the question in the title is too broad for your problem, and the only other question in your text is "Any help here?" :-).

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the trick below to see all raw http requests that boto sends to S3:

```python
import httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
```

also you could use this hint for the same:

```python
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="boto.log", level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Before testing functionality using web server please try to execute some test code from default python console:

```python
import httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id='some', aws_secret_access_key='some')
b = conn.get_bucket('snappie.watermarks')
k = Key(b)
k.key = "test.txt"
k.set_contents_from_string('12345')
```

After this please check file existence. In any case after all manipulations you should execute:

```python
key.make_public()
```

Because by default all new bucket objects aren't public.

Comment: I don't understand what where the string '12345' comes from? If I was opening the file from a url like in my question's code, how would I set it as a string?

Comment: In your example you save some image on disk and after that try to create S3 key using content from this image. I suggest you to create some **test key** on bucket using some abstract code (and string 12345 as a content) to make sure that you have no any problems with access to bucket or may be some other access restrictions.

Comment: when I try that, It does seem to create something, but when I view it, it gives me a XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it error for the "test.png" key that I create. Im not sure if this means that it was created or not?

Comment: Please, use some specific tool to check file existence on S3. For example, you can use http://www.dragondisk.com . Also don't forget about key.make_public() . Without this command your new bucket object couldn't be seen from internet.

Comment: hmm actually, its not being created at all. I am checking my amazon s3 account in that bucket directly and no file exists under then key name that I set. I really think its just erroring out because I am not converting the file correctly before it even gets to the amazon s3 stuff.